# Grabbing stdout of a function with multiprocessing

Tags: python

I have a Python function which accepts an argument and prints a number of text lines to stdout. I grab the stdout of this function and extract the relevant information.

The call to this function is very costly, it takes few minutes to complete. To speed up the computations, I use Python multiprocessing to run this function in parallel. The problem is now how to differentiate the stdout of each worker?

What could be the simplest way to keep track of each workers output to stdout? Can I redirect each workers output to some file descriptor and then read each file descriptor at the other end?

Note: I have no control over the function writing to stdout.

Comment: Which Python version? In 3.x, you can just shadow the builtin `print` to customize what it does; in 2.x, the closest equivalent to that is to replace `sys.stdout` with a file-like object with a custom `write`. Similarly, in 3.4, it's pretty easy to replace the stdio file descriptors for each child process with new pipes, but in 3.1 or 2.7 it requires digging under the covers. And so on.

Comment: Also, which platform(s) do you care about (or, if on 3.4+ and using an explicit start method, which one)?

Comment: Finally, are you using a separate `Process` for each call, or are you tossing them as tasks into a `Pool`?

Comment: I am currently using 2.7. I am currently looking whether each worker can replace sys.stdout with a specificly opened file descriptor. I would like to redirect its output to that descriptor. Wondering if this change is not global...

Comment: @abarnert I currently use Pool but can easily modify it to uses Process. The latter allows to pass more arguments I believe.

Comment: Well, there are advantages to using a Pool, but if you're using a Process for each one, you can guarantee that the child initializer code gets run exactly once per job, while if you're using a Pool, that's obviously not true. Meanwhile, as for whether it's global… that's why I asked you all those questions. If you don't answer all of them, all I can say is "maybe, it depends", which isn't very helpful.

Comment: So, it looks like Process is the right choice. I want each worker to run only once and be identified by some integer. This integer can be used to redirect stdout to some file descriptor/stream/whatever. When it comes time to read, this integer should enable to effectively demultiplex the all outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using a separate `Process` for each task (which has downsides—e.g., running 200 tasks all at once will generally be slower than running 8 at a time, especially if you're on a platform like Windows where process spawning is a bit expensive—but may be worth it), this isn't too hard to do.

The first key is that you have to replace `sys.stdout` in the child process, not the parent. Where can you do that? You can either subclass `Process` to make the `run` method first do your setup work, and then call the super's `run`, or you can wrap each task's function in a function that first does the setup work, then calls the real function.

Next, what can you replace it *with*? You can have it write to a separate [`Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe) that's passed in by the parent process. And, at least on Unix, just setting `sys.stdout` to a pipe's write end should just work. But I'm not sure it does on Windows. So if you want it to be cross-platform (and since you won't tell me what platform(s) you care about, that appears to be necessary), writing to files is dead simple:

For example:

```
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

def wrap(task, name):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        with open(os.path.join(tempdir, name), 'w') as f:
            sys.stdout = f
            task(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

procs = []
for i in range(8):
    name = str(i)
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrap(task, name), name=name, ...)
    proc.start()
    procs.append(proc)
for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
    with open(os.path.join(tempdir, proc.name)) as f:
        do_stuff_with(f.read())
shutil.rmtree(tempdir)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the sample code. And sorry for not answering to all clarifying questions. First, I am going to run as many processes as cores on the machine (8 in my case). This will be done in batches of 8. Second, I am developing on Linux, there is no immediate need to port it to Windows. Finally, writing to files is not ok since the output of each worker will be reused in a loop. It would be better to get the results of all workers in a list for further processing.

Comment: @xeon: I don't understand why "the output of each worker will be reused in a loop" means "writing to files is not ok". Each worker gets a different filename, and you can read from files in a loop. But, as I already said in the answer, if you only care about Unix, just passing in a `Pipe` and setting `sys.stdout` to its write end and `read`ing from it in the parent should be fine. You may need to worry about servicing all the pipes in parallel to avoid blocking, but `select` works just fine on pipes in Unix, so that's easy. (Or you can use a listener thread per process, if you prefer.)

Comment: It is just a preference to not write to a file if I could just store the results in memory. My application is about calling batches of 8 repeatedly hence the preference. The amount to be written is small, couple of hundreds of text lines per worker.

Comment: @xeon: You can't really store the results "in memory"; they have to go over some kind of IPC. On Unix, pipes are files (like almost everything); they may not be backed by a path rooted in `/`, they may not be backed to disk, etc. And pipes have the added problem of a max buffer. But anyway, if it's performance you're worried about, you may be surprised about the different costs for writing a tempfile, mmapping a file, using POSIX shared mem, using a pipe, etc. Don't just assume "files are slow" if you need to optimize; try it each way and see.

Comment: Thanks! If writing to files makes the matters simpler, this is the way to go. My application requires function evaluation in batches by 8. I can write to 8 files, read them and discard; then repeat the process.