# Why is my function not printing the string in multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

i try to understand multiprocessing in depth. So far it is going good and I understood the concept. Now however I'm wondering, why my print statement is not showing up, when using multiprocessing.

Does anyone know where my mistake is or why the print argument is not showing up in multiprocessing?

**This is my code and output without multiprocessing:**

```
# -------------------------LINEAR PROCESSING--------------------------- # 
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def sleep(seconds):
    print("Sleeping {} second(s) ...".format(seconds))
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done Sleeping...")

# run sleep function 10 times
for _ in range(10): # _ throw away variable - hence not using integers of range
    sleep(1.5)

finish = time.perf_counter()

print("Finished in {} second(s) without multi-processing".format(round(finish-start,2)))

# Output
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Sleeping 1.5 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Finished in 15.03 second(s) without multi-processing
```

**This is my code and output with multiprocessing:**

```
# -------------------------MULTI-PROCESSING (OLD WAY)--------------------------- # 
import multiprocessing
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def sleep(seconds):
    print("Sleeping {} second(s) ...".format(seconds))
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done Sleeping...")

# create 10 processes for each sleep function and store it in list
processes = []
for _ in range(10): # _ throw away variable - hence not using integers of range
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleep, args=[1.5])
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

# loop over started processes and wait until all processes are finished (join)
for process in processes:
    process.join()
    

finish = time.perf_counter()

print("Finished in {} second(s) with multi-processing".format(round(finish-start,2)))

# Output
Finished in 0.14 second(s) with multi-processing
```

**Here are my jupyter notebook stats:**

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : 5.0.3
ipython          : 7.22.0
ipykernel        : 5.3.4
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.14
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.6.3
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but I thnk each process will have its own `stdout` rather than the same output as your main script. To read the stdout from the different processes you would need to either re-direct or read those streams. Similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793624/grabbing-stdout-of-a-function-with-multiprocessing

Comment: Or rather than using print, output the string to a queue that can then be read by the main script and output to the console.

Comment: Thank you! However, the problem was not using the __ name __ == "__ main __": line, since this script called a system call from another one, which also had the time module in it and was not guarded.

Comment: @scotty3785 stdout is copied from the main process, but jupyter re-directs (and post-processes) stdout and doesn't tell the kids. That's why child `print` works fine on a system terminal with no redirection tomfoolery involved. This is also common with pycharm and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer (kind of) to my problem:**

Firstly, i re-run my code in visual studio. There i found out, that when i started the Process, it was not forking the child processes.

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)

        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
  File "/Users/philipp/Desktop/Processing.py", line 18, in <module>
    p.start()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> (Current frame)
```

After digging deeper, i found out, that using freeze_support() is only necessary when using Windows OS (I'm using IOS).

**However using the __ name __ == "__ main __": argument and placing the multiprocessing in there did the job. This is the re-factored code, which works in visual studio code with the given output:**

```
# -------------------------MULTI-PROCESSING (OLD WAY)--------------------------- # 
import multiprocessing
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

def sleep(seconds):
    print("Sleeping {} second(s) ...".format(seconds))
    time.sleep(seconds)
    print("Done Sleeping...")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # create 10 processes for each sleep function and store it in list
    processes = []
    for _ in range(10): # _ throw away variable - hence not using integers of range
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleep, args=[1])
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)

    # loop over started processes and wait until all processes are finished (join)
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
            
    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print("Finished in {} second(s) with multi-processing".format(round(finish-start,2)))

# Output
Sleeping 1 second(s) ...
Sleeping 1 second(s) ...
Sleeping 1 second(s) ...Sleeping 1 second(s) ...

Sleeping 1 second(s) ...
Sleeping 1 second(s) ...Sleeping 1 second(s) ...
Sleeping 1 second(s) ...
Sleeping 1 second(s) ...

Sleeping 1 second(s) ...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...Done Sleeping...

Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Done Sleeping...
Finished in 2.51 second(s) with multi-processing
```

**Some remarks:**

- This is only working in visual studio code (in jupyter notebook it's still not working - it seems like jupyter notebook is not recognizing the multiprocessing module at all, hence the fast finish time < 1 sec. This makes no sense, since the sleeping time is 1 sec..)
- **Really important:** At first the guardless script without __ name __ == "__ main __" invoked another guardless script, since it also had the module time in it. Therefore, the latter script also started a system call. This somehow led to a critical section.

Comment: Glad you were able to answer your own question! Here's some extra thoughts: Do some extra reading into the difference between "spawn vs fork" on why `if __name__ == "__main__":` is needed in some cases. It is also important in why spawn does not always work properly when using an interactive prompt (like jupyter). Finally `freeze_support` is further only necessary on windows **when you intend to use something like py2exe** to convert your script to windows PE format

Comment: Thank you! I will look more deeply into this topic.